# How to install and set up the ODF-DOM API

Tags: java, odf, opendocument, odftoolkit

I am having troubles with the installation and set-up if the [odf-toolkit](https://odftoolkit.org/index.html).

I tried to follow [this instruction](https://odftoolkit.org/downloads.html) but don't understand how to set up the dependencies since some of the instruction-links from the readme-files are gone.

Tips or instructions would be very apprectiated

**Edit: It is better to use the ODF-DOM API instead. Changed the title from 'How to install and set up the ODF toolkit'**

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed it.

It is better to use the [ODF-DOM](https://odftoolkit.org/odfdom/index.html) API rather then the odf-toolkit since the latter is not maintained any more and they share similar functionalities.

One has to download the **Binaries** at the download page, extract the .jar files from inside of the zip-file and safe them in a folder in the directory of the Java project.
Also go to the IDE and enable each of the jar files in the folder as a library.
There is also a [odf dom documentation](https://odftoolkit.org/api/odfdom/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

How you can do it using **Maven**:

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.odftoolkit</groupId>
  <artifactId>odfdom-java</artifactId>
  <version>0.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

module-info.java:

```
requires odfdom.java;
```

In class:

```
import org.odftoolkit.odfdom.doc.*;
import org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.*;
import org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.*;
```